# Simple addition string to int with C#

Tags: c#, string, int, addition

I have knowledge in PHP and I want to learn C # language but I do not even do simple addition.

I want to get the value of a ComboBox, convert this value to int and be able to add another value

Despite the conversion done, I have an error : Can not convert type "int" to "string.

My code :

```
    private void btnValidate_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int number = Test();
    }

    int Test()
    {
        string day = DayBirth.Text;

        int number;
        bool isNumeric = int.TryParse(day, out number);

        if (isNumeric == false)
        {
            Resultat1.Text = "This is not a number";
        }
        else
        {
            Resultat1.Text = number + 10;
        }

        return number;
    }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that Resultat1.Text is expecting a string, not an int. You can do

```
Resultat1.Text = (number+10).ToString();
```

and it should work.

Comment: Thank you for your help it's ok ;)

Answer (score 1):

what you need to do is Converting your number to string after addition

```
Resultat1.Text = (number + 10).ToString;
```

Answer (score 1):

`Text` property accept string value not integer so after addition you have to convert it as string

```
Resultat1.Text = (number + 10).ToString();
```